# Too many nested views/persistent user-defined functions

Tags: google-bigquery

Sql generated by looker is throwing below error. I took the sql and ran in production big query  it is throwing the same error. I ran the same query in Development big query and QA big query region and I do not get the error and Query ran fine and generated output. What do you think the reason for the query failing in Production but not in dev & QA environment.

Error Message:
Too many nested views/persistent user-defined functions or possible circular reference of views/persistent user-defined functions referenced in query. Only 16 levels of nested views/persistent user-defined functions are allowed.